# install4j installer variable UndefinedVariableException

Tags: install4j

There is an installer variable which is bound with value 1.1.
When I am trying to use it with screen title/subtitle its working fine.
[image: Variable value shown in subtitle]

When I am using it with info text it throws **UndefinedVariableException**. 
[image: Error in Info Text]

I imported variable in info text through code editor, so I dont have any doubt in syntax. Is it a normal behavior? even then it should not appear in code editor.Please suggest how a installer variable can be used in info text.

Replicated scenario with install4j 6.1.1 and 6.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 6.1.3, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this already fixed.