# Install4j - UndefinedVariableException for installer variable

Tags: install4j

I know there has been a [bug on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605315/install4j-installer-variable-undefinedvariableexception), but it seems I'm still getting this error when the installer running on Linux environment (on windows it working fine).
I'm using v6.1.6 [build: 6459]

What I tried to do:

1. I defined a `Set a variable` action in which I'm getting the *$JAVA_HOME* path if exists and set it to `linuxJavaHome` variable.

[image]

2. Later on - I defined `Run executable or batch file` action in which I'm getting the java version using the installer previous `linuxJavaHome` variable.

[image]

I checked my code on multiple Linux environments and the variable is defined just fine with the java home path. Moreover, I've also tried debugging my code to be sure and it seems OK.

[image]

My only problem is when I'm building and running our installer from JENKINS with silent mode (-q), I'm always getting this *UndefinedVariableException*. I refined the problematic point and it happens on the 1st `Set a variable` screen.

The exception stacktrace is:

```
com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:linuxJavaHome
13:03:08 Error log: /home/administrator/installer/install4jError2195873440024941405.log
13:03:08 com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:linuxJavaHome
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.handleError(InstallerVariables.java:971)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables$InstallerReplacementCallback.getReplacement(InstallerVariables.java:950)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.util.StringUtil.replaceVariable(StringUtil.java:68)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(InstallerVariables.java:337)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(InstallerVariables.java:326)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(InstallerVariables.java:322)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerVariables.replaceVariables(InstallerVariables.java:362)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.api.beans.AbstractBean.replaceVariables(AbstractBean.java:89)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.getExecutable(RunExecutableAction.java:58)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction.execute(RunExecutableAction.java:292)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.install(SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.java:29)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.executeAction(ContextImpl.java:1668)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1659)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$7.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1656)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:274)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:259)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionChecked(HelperCommunication.java:187)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.fetchObjectChecked(HelperCommunication.java:170)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performActionIntStatic(ContextImpl.java:1656)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.performActionInt(InstallerContextImpl.java:151)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performAction(ContextImpl.java:1103)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeAction(Controller.java:368)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:334)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActionGroup(Controller.java:405)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:339)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActionGroup(Controller.java:405)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:339)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:195)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleStartup(Controller.java:116)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:73)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:59)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
13:03:08    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
13:03:08    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
13:03:08    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
13:03:08    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
13:03:08    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
13:03:08    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Sure. I posted it to my original post since I cannot add it as a comment (too long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what was working for me was neglecting the use of the $JAVA_HOME variable and using the installer inner variable `${installer:sys.javaHome}` which works great both on Linux & Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The "Set a variable" action probably sets a null variable value because the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not defined. You can select the "Fail if value is null" property of that action to catch this problem earlier.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this option and it did fail with the error message. I don't understand why though. All our Linux machines do have JAVA_HOME variable. Maybe there is another way getting the Linux env, not by System.getenv?

Comment: I don't see any other way. The calling process may not pass the environment variables.

Comment: Is there any way of using Linux syntax like **locate java** command through the install4j?

Comment: Yes, you can use a "Run executable" action to execute it and save the output to an installer variable. However, that executable will also have the wrong environment variables because they are inherited. Maybe if you execute it via `/bin/sh` you start with the original environment variables. Alternatively I would look at the invocation of the installer, maybe there is an option to pass all environment variables, or you can specify a parameter with the value of JAVA_HOME that you can use in the installer.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Ingo.
About the 2nd paragrath you wrote - do you mean defining the variable as a 'pre-defined' variable? Do you think in this case it might help the variable to be set later on?

Comment: No, I meant passing it to the installer as an argument of the form `-VmyJavaHome=value`, this will define the installer variable `${installer:myJavaHome}`.